# Debug Android vibration

Tags: android, android-vibration

Guys my phone is vibration without any reason. So I want to determine the application which sends vibration command to vibrate. Does Android logging such events? Or can I write an application which will monitor `Vibrator::vibrate(TIMEOUT)` calls from another application?

Note:
I have root access.

Comment: Do you get any notification when device vibs

Comment: No, nothing. Notification bar is clear(except of standard icons like battery, GSM network status.)

Comment: You may have [Phantom Vibration Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_vibration_syndrome). Consider supporting the [Health](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) site proposal.

Comment: I haven't such syndrome. Vibrations is real.

Comment: BTW, I've disabled WiFi on the phone, and there is not vibrations last 30 minutes. But still I want do debug to find the real problem.

Comment: Wait until it starts vibrating again, then kill processes one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the system log (`logcat -b system`) it will show you the core system service's logs.  The VibrateService only makes a couple in the latest version of Android, which will tell you what vibration pattern is being started.  Unfortunately, it won't show you what UID/PID is responsible for the request.  Beyond that, you may be able to find some information from the kernel by digging around to figure out which device interface (e.g. `/dev/gpio1`) is the one used by the vibrator service.  If that driver exposes some stats/debug on `/proc` or `debugfs` you might be able to figure out which process is responsible.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try. I found an issue: seems like when the device tries to connect to a known WiFi network but uses wrong password, phone starts vibrate to indicate the connection error.