# Android Emulator Vibration Test?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-vibration

Is there a way to test vibrations on the Virtual Devices that come with Android Studio?

I tried searching logcat and it seems like there isn't any indication of when the Android device is vibrating or not.

Comment: Wondering the same thing, nothing in logcat, did you find you answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
logcat -b system
```

(Look into this answer: [Debug Android vibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115853/debug-android-vibration))

Othere than that, if you are writing the code, the vibration is called with the method

```
Vibrator.vibrate().
```

You could write a wrapper around this or create your own vibrator class to add some specific logging next to the vibration call itself.